# Install GraphLab Package in python 3.6.1

Tags: python, text-mining, graphlab

I tried to install GraphLab, but the result became like this:

**AttributeError: module 'graphlab' has no attribute 'connect'**

My python version is 3.6.1. And I also tried the code:

`python -m pip install connect`

But it didn't work.

Does anyone know how to solve this problems? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This happens when Version in python on system is different from Anaconda. Anaconda Python is mixing in imports from the regular Python on the system. Make sure "which python" points to the right Python (whereever you installed Anaconda Python. And similarly "which pip" Otherwise you will want to run python (or pip) from [where ever you installed Anaconda]/bin/python. You can try the **Dato Launcher**  which tries to set it all up for you.

Also, if you are not using Anaconda, on Graphlab support of installation, they recommended only two option for installation, one on Anaconda and the other on Virtualenv. I personally recommend you to use Anaconda for Graphlab as most of the development support and learning is totally based on Anaconda usage. You may follow this link to install Graphlab and Anaconda [Here](https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html). I hope this helps.

Note: In installation of Anaconda, Python Version can be different like `Python 2.7`, but after installation of Anaconda, you can update to latest version of your choice.

Comment: As per its documentation, graphlab can only be installed in python version 2.7.x
https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html