# GraphLab installation when Python 2.7 is no longer supported

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, version, graphlab

i need to install GraphLab in jupyter notebook to do a coursera project but all instructions that i found and my research in stackoverflow shows that it require python-2.x or now python-2.7 is no longer supported so what can i do ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44963163/install-graphlab-package-in-python-3-6-1) answer your question?

Comment: @Johnny yeah it is similar to mine but ther is no answer ,  graphlab require python-2.x and now it is no longer supported so is there any alternative or solution ?

Comment: There's not much you can do. Python 2.x is deprecated, and per [these instructions](https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html), GraphLab only allows Python 2.x.

Comment: Python 2.7 still exists, even if it's no longer receiving updates. I'd avoid it if you can in the future, but just install it and use it for your course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue. This is how I solved it. I hope it'll help you too.

1. First, you need to open your anaconda navigator.
2. Then Go to the Environment tab. 
   [image]
3. Click create option
4. Then provide a name for your environment and choose the appropriate python version. (GraphLab Create installation requires a Python 2.7.x environment and pip version >= 7)
   [image]
5. When your environment ready you can open it with the terminal as follows.[image]
6. In command prompt type `conda update pip` to ensure pip is updated to the latest version
7. Now run this command `pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir https://get.graphlab.com/GraphLab-Create/2.1/your registered email address here/your product key here/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz`
8. To Install or update IPython and IPython Notebook
   `conda install ipython-notebook`

I hope it will help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Step 4. Creating conda env is taking a long time and seems not working. The following is the error in conda prompt:

```
Users\sharone\Anaconda2>conda create -n gl-env python=2.7 anaconda=4.0.0
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: .
Error:  Dependencies missing in current win-64 channels:
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scipy 0.17.0 np110py27_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numpy 1.10.4 py35_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scipy 0.17.0 np110py34_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scikit-learn 0.17.1 np110py27_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numexpr 2.5 np110py35_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scikit-learn 0.17.1 np110py34_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py35_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> numpy 1.11* -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py34_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> numpy 1.11* -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scipy 0.17.0 np110py35_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py27_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> numpy 1.11* -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py35_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numpy 1.10.4 py34_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numexpr 2.5 np110py34_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numpy 1.10.4 py27_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scikit-learn 0.17.1 np110py35_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py27_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py34_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numexpr 2.5 np110py27_0 -> blas * mkl
```

You can search for this package on anaconda.org with:

```
anaconda search -t conda blas * mkl
```

Comment: Are you sure that is an answer to the question?

Comment: the steps mentioned were successully executed. 
but import graphlab in python terminal resulted in error. 
execution is shown below. Hepl needed. 
Thanks in advance.

(C:\Users\sharone\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env) C:\Users\sharone\Documents>python
Python 2.7.18 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 23 2020, 17:26:54) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import graphlab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named graphlab

Comment: **anaconda search -t conda blas * mkl**   (C:\Users\sharone\Anaconda2) C:\Users\sharone>anaconda search -t conda blas * mkl  
usage: anaconda-script.py [-h] [--show-traceback] [--hide-traceback] [-v] [-q]
                          [--color] [--no-color] [-V] [-t TOKEN] [-s SITE]
                          ...
anaconda-script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: * mkl

(C:\Users\sharone\Anaconda2) C:\Users\sharone>